# My application screen should be on for 5 minutes and then lock the screen

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I want my application to be on for 5 min if the app is idle and then lock the screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Settings->Display->Sleep->5 minutes. :-D

Comment: ok.. I will try this..